# How to detect if Home Activity is currently on the top of ActivityStack

Tags: android, service, android-activity

I want to detect current foreground activity from a background service.

Particularly I want to know if Home activity is currently on the top of android activity stack or not.

Use case is something like: If home activity is on foreground (i.e User is not using any other application) I need to show a alert dialog on some event in background service. But if, Home activity is not on top of stack (i.e. user is using some other application), i am supposed to show a notification in status bar on some event in service.

Is there any way to detect current foreground activity?

Comment: I know that this behavior is not as per Android UI guidelines. But I need to follow requirements.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See this
[here](http://qtcstation.com/2011/01/getting-info-about-your-currently-running-activities/)

Here you can find the foreground Activity then compare its package with the home package.Its may be android.home

Comment: Thanks Rasel. 
We can detect native Home screen (native Activity which is in com.android.launcher package), but if user has installed any custom launcher (like GO Launcher) this method wont work as the base package will be anything different than com.android.launcher and home screen can't be detected in such case.

Even though this is not a fullproof method, still this will solve my purpose for the time-being. Thanks for the answer. I am marking it as accepted.

Comment: Just as a help for other readers: How to detect package names for Home activity programatically - http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/fb968648e77027ef/7b622be6130795ab

Answer (score 0):

You can get your home activity to bind to the service in `onResume()`, and notify the service that it's running. Then in `onPause()` you can make another call to the service to notify it the activity is no longer in the foreground, and unbind.

Answer (score 0):

May be this works:

This will launch the home screen-

```
    Intent i = new Intent(); 
    i.setAction(Intent.ACTION_MAIN); 
    i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME); 
    startActivity(i);
```

Now, check for the top activity-

```
    ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(Activity.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
    String packageName = am.getRunningTasks(1).get(0).topActivity.getPackageName();
```

I have not tried this, but it should work.

Answer (score 0):

I've used this which works fine for both default and custom launchers:

```
boolean isOnHomeApp() {
    final Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
    intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
    final ResolveInfo res = getPackageManager().resolveActivity(intent, 0);

    ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(Activity.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
    String packageName = am.getRunningTasks(1).get(0).topActivity.getPackageName();
    if (res.activityInfo != null && packageName.equals(res.activityInfo.packageName)) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: `am.getRunningTasks(1).get(0).topActivity.getPackageName()` always returns the launcher package in my case, I guess that's because "As of `LOLLIPOP`, this method is no longer available to third party applications: the introduction of document-centric recents means it can leak person information to the caller. For backwards compatibility, it will still return a small subset of its data: at least the caller's own tasks, and possibly some other tasks such as home that are known to not be sensitive."